# JQuery to be used with PHP to get the second list

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am using a JQuery function which call an other function on live change event occur on a select list.
Here is my JQuery function

```
    var formObject = {
    run : function(obj) {
        if (obj.val() === '') {
            obj.next('#indlist').html('<option value="">Select Topic First</option>').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            var v = obj.val();
            jQuery.getJSON('/lib/update.php', {topicid : v }, function(data) {
                if (!data.error) {
                    obj.next('#indlist').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    obj.nextAll('#indlist').html('<option value="">Select Topic Correctly</option>').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            });
        }
    }
};
$(function() {

    $('#update').live('change', function() {
        formObject.run($(this));
    });

});
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<div class="dropdownlist">
    <form action="" method="post">
       <table width="500px">
       <tr>
       <td>
        <select name="gender" id="update">
            <option value="">Select one</option>
            <?php if (!empty($list)) { ?>
                <?php foreach($list as $row) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['topicid']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $row['topicname']; ?>
                    </option>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </td></tr><tr><td>
        <select name="category" id="indlist"
            disabled="disabled">
            <option value="">----</option>
        </select>
        </td></tr></table>
    </form>
</div>
```

but it is not working and did not populate the next select list

Answer (score 1):

The error is in `.next()` maybe.

`#indlist` is in a completely different DOM branch, you can't expect `.next()` to find it because it finds the next **sibling**:

```
TR
  TD
    SELECT#update
    ?? <---- .next("#indlist")? There's no obj after #update with that id!
  /TD
/TR
TR 
  TD
    SELECT#indlist
  /TD
/TR
```

If `#indlist` is unique (it **should** be if you are using an id!), just use `$("#indlist")`.

```
$("#indlist").html("<option ... etc.>");
```

If not, better use a class (`<select class='indlist' ...>`) and find the element:

```
$(obj).parent("table").find(".indlist")
```

Note that I use `$(obj)` and not `obj`, too.

By the way also `.nextAll("#indlist")` makes no sense: as I said, **"id"s must be unique in the document**, try to use a class instead if there is more than one.

---

Sidenote: I think `<?php if (!empty($list)) { ?>` can be dropped, if `$list` is empty the for-each loop won't fire.

Answer (score 0):

You  are using next() method incorrectly.

### next()

> **Description**: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Since your select tags are the only element in their parent TD's they have no siblings.

To get to next select in your code you need to traverse up to parent, go to parent's sibling and find the select there

BUT: The select has an ID. So just use the ID as selector.

Replace:

```
obj.next('#indlist').html....
```

With

```
$('#indlist').html.....
```

Do the same with `obj.nextAll('#indlist')`